# Getting counts for different clauses within one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a more efficient or something in better practice to get counts than what I am doing below?

```
select
   i.org_id,
   o.Org_Name_1,
   count(*) as 'Total Users',
   SUM(CASE WHEN i.email is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'No Email'
from
   individu i,
   organiz o
where
   i.org_id = o.org_id
group by
   i.org_id, o.Org_Name_1
order by
   count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN i.email is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'No Email'
```

can be replaced with because... *Quoted from [MSDN Count(Transact SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)*

> COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values.

When an expression is place in the parenthesis of the COUNT statement, it will evaluate and count only non-null values in that field. Therefore, if you take Count(*) - Count(field) you get the total of all null fields.

```
COUNT(*) - COUNT(i.email) AS 'No Email'
```

Your Query would then look like this:

```
SELECT
   i.org_id,
   o.Org_Name_1,
   COUNT(*) AS 'Total Users',
   COUNT(*) - COUNT(i.email) AS 'No Email'
FROM
   individu i,
   organiz o
WHERE
   i.org_id = o.org_id
GROUP BY
   i.org_id, o.Org_Name_1
ORDER BY
   COUNT(*) DESC
```